# What is the Python equivalent of MATLAB's lti.bandwidth function?

Tags: python

Good day, I want to determine the bandwidth of a Transfer function in Python, I'm using the `control` package, but I can't find it's equivalent. I've googled everywhere, but I always get different results that are not related with control.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.bandwidth.html

Comment: I am not sure if it was you, but someone just opened an issue on the package project github: https://github.com/python-control/python-control/issues/690 which is a valid idea to improve it.